# Create Outlook-like Menu/Submenu on the Windows 7 Start Menu using C#

Tags: c#

I want to ship my own application (written in C#) with a menu/submenu entry similar to the Outlook menu entry on the Windows 7 start menu:

[image]

How can I archieve this? Is there any documentation about those menu/submenu entries?

Comment: its called a jump list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

It's known as [Taskbar Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378460(v=vs.85).aspx), specifically [Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378460(v=vs.85).aspx#tasks) and [Jump Lists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378460(v=vs.85).aspx#custom_jump_lists).

MSDN:

> Another built-in portion of a Jump List is the Tasks category. While a destination is a thing, a task is an action, and in this case it is an application-specific action. Put another way, a destination is a noun and a task is a verb. Typically, tasks are IShellLink items with command-line arguments that indicate particular functionality that can be triggered by an application. Again, the idea is to centralize as much information related to an application as is practical.
>
> Applications define tasks based on both the program's features and the key things a user is expected to do with them. Tasks should be context-free, in that the application does not need to be running for them to work.  [more...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378460(v=vs.85).aspx)

In c#, refer to the [TaskbarItemInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.taskbariteminfo(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples) class.

Here's a Task example for a WPF app, courtesy [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell.taskbariteminfo(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples):

```
<Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
    <TaskbarItemInfo x:Name="taskBarItemInfo1" 
                     Overlay="{StaticResource ResourceKey=StopImage}"
                     ThumbnailClipMargin="80,0,80,140"
                     Description="Taskbar Item Info Sample">
        <TaskbarItemInfo.ThumbButtonInfos>
            <ThumbButtonInfoCollection>
                <ThumbButtonInfo
                    DismissWhenClicked="False"
                    Command="MediaCommands.Play"
                    CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=btnPlay}"
                    Description="Play"
                    ImageSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PlayImage}"/>
                <ThumbButtonInfo
                    DismissWhenClicked="True"
                    Command="MediaCommands.Stop"
                    CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=btnStop}"
                    Description="Stop"
                    ImageSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey=StopImage}"/>
            </ThumbButtonInfoCollection>
        </TaskbarItemInfo.ThumbButtonInfos>
    </TaskbarItemInfo>
</Window.TaskbarItemInfo>
```

You might want to look at `System.Windows.Shell.JumpTask` too.